# Cam Link 4K - was working, but now it isn't

Tags: 20.04, webcam, zoom-meeting, v4l

20.04 on a Lenovo X1 carbon, if it matters

I have a Cam Link 4K USB HDMI adapter, the purpose of which is to connect the HDMI output of a camera to a USB input. I have managed to get it working in the past. However, I had to reboot today, and now, though I can get the device to work with `cheese`, it does not work with any of the meeting applications I use (`zoom` and `ringcentral`).

I have a locally-built version of the `v42loopback` module, and I've installed it with

```
modprobe v4l2loopback max_buffers=2 devices=1 exclusive_caps=1
```

My `v42l-ctl` output is:

```
% v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video0

Synaptics RMI4 Touch Sensor (rmi4:rmi4-00.fn54):
    /dev/v4l-touch0

Cam Link 4K: Cam Link 4K (usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2):
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/media0
```

I then start `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 50 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video1 -f v4l2 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video0
```

I don't completely understand what that means, but it has worked for me many times in the past. Now, when I try all this stuff, I can get my video input up on the screen via `cheese`. That is, I start `cheese` and it works; I see the video and it's obviously live.

However, unlike in the past, the video is unavailable in `zoom` or `ringcentral`; the applications simply do not allow video. I have no clue at all what could be going on, or even any way of diagnosing the issue; the video is simply not available.

What can I do to figure out what those applications need in order to get the video working again?

*edit* I do verify the device info when I start `ffmpeg` to make sure the device assignments are correct; the above `v42l-ctl` output is *usually* how things look, but for random reasons the devices are different sometimes.

Comment: Note: after re-installing it, `obs` started working. That is, while `cheese` was working OK, `obs` was not until I reinstalled it. I have no idea why, as `obs` was working fine previously.

Comment: I'll also note that it's incredibly flaky; starting `cheese` *often* works, but then minutes later it doesn't, for reasons unknown.

Comment: Also: sometimes the camera works with `vlc` just fine, but `cheese` can't handle it because of some internal errors about allocating a buffer (?).

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

sudo usbreset "Cam Link 4K"

you may need to run "sudo apt install usbutils" to get the usbreset command.